# Is OpenID Connect (OIDC) a solution for Github Actions being unable to check out a repo on a Github-hosted runner due to IP allowlist policies?

Tags: github, jwt, github-actions, openid-connect

My organization hosts code on github.com enterprise. As a security measure we are using Github's IP allowlisting policy to a static set of IP's, such as corporate VPN and things like that.

However, we need to make use of [Github-hosted](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners) runners, e.g. `ubuntu-latest`. These are resources provided by Github and therefore these virtual machines have public IP addresses that fall outside of our IP allowlist. This means that when we try to do anything on that VM as unremarkable as `actions/checkout@v3` to checkout the repo on which the Github workflow is running, we run into the problem of [`remote: The repository owner has an IP allow list enabled, and xx.xx.xx.xxx is not permitted to access this repository.`](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27106)

Now, the linked discussion shows that the solution some people found is to simply add the IP range of all Github Actions runners. Not to say that won't fix the immediate problem, but doesn't that present a security vulnerability? It seems possible that after allowlisting all Github Actions runner IP's, anyone outside of the organization could simply clone our organization code as long as they execute it within a Github Actions VM?

Anyway, assuming I'm right, then how can we *securely* make use of Github-hosted runners without opening up our proprietary code up to any users of Github Actions?

I found this article [About private networking with GitHub-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/connecting-to-a-private-network/about-private-networking-with-github-hosted-runners).

> By default, GitHub-hosted runners have access to the public internet. However, you may also want these runners to access resources on your private network, such as a package registry, a secret manager, or other on-premise services.
>
> GitHub-hosted runners are shared across all GitHub customers, so you will need a way of connecting your private network to just your runners while they are running your workflows. There are a few different approaches you could take to configure this access, each with different advantages and disadvantages.
>
> With GitHub Actions, you can use OpenID Connect (OIDC) tokens to authenticate your workflow outside of GitHub Actions. For more information, see "Using an API gateway with OIDC."

Now, this all seems promising but none of this explicitly mentions the problem I'm trying to solve which is securely getting around organization IP allowlists.

Suppose I was to implement OIDC in my workflow ~ Github Actions comes baked with the environment variables `$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN` and `$ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL`. There's even a little guide [here](https://blog.alexellis.io/deploy-without-credentials-using-oidc-and-github-actions/) from someone who demonstrates the process of getting the OIDC token. That token contains a JWT key with some metadata about the user making the request and stuff like that.

What am I supposed to do with that OIDC token? How does that get me past a Github repo allowlist? Is it even designed for that? These questions I could not find any answers to online.

Comment: See [Using WireGuard to create a network overlay](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/connecting-to-a-private-network/about-private-networking-with-github-hosted-runners#using-wireguard-to-create-a-network-overlay). Seems more relevant to your use case.